# Why don't math departments use Mathjobs for postgraduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, job-search, website

It is common practice for mathematics department hiring to use [Mathjobs](https://www.mathjobs.org/) (especially in the US).  This is very convenient for recommendation letter writers, as we can just upload one letter that the applicant can send to all the the different schools.

However, very few mathematics departments use mathjobs for postgraduate admissions (exceptions include the University of Oklahoma which uses Mathjobs for PhD applications). So for students applying for math masters/phd programmes, recommendation letter writers have to spend lots of time navigating each university's individual admissions website.

I was wondering why so many departments are willing to use Mathjobs for postdoc/assistant professor level hiring, but so few use it for PhD/Masters admission?

Comment: I suspect that the proposed duplicate answers your question: on PhD/MSc level, there are just so many candidates, and so frequent searches, that it makes sense for the university to centralize the process. You hire far fewer postdocs and professors, so the university might be happy with humoring the mathematicians and their special requests.